# Photoshop: Lens Correction filter not available

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-effects, filter

I want to create a vignette effect, but I can't figure out how to open the dialogue box for  Lens Correction.

[image: No lens correction]

Comment: Try to use its shortcut: Shift + Ctrl + R.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure your document in not CMYK, as the 'Lens Correction' filter only works with RGB or Grayscale documents.

> The filter works only with 8‑ and 16‑bit-per-channel images in RGB or Grayscale mode. ([source](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/correcting-image-distortion-noise.html))

Comment: Unfortunately, the document is already RGB 16bit. I've tried with RGB 8bit, and 8/16bit on grayscale. Still not there.

Comment: Pretty sure this is a document related issue and nothing to do with the actual software. Something in your document prevents the filter from showing up. To make sure, create a new RGB doc with a white background and see if the filter shows up (it does on my machine using PS CS6).

Comment: Nope... :( Nothing happened.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, check in Prefs if all Plugins are displayed:

[image]

Note: You'll have to restart PS after changes.

What Photoshop version do you use? PC or Mac? Some 32-bit tools got lost when older Photoshop versions were running on a 64-bit system. IIRC on a Mac you were able to force Photoshop to run in 32-bit mode via the Finder info panel.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like some of the tools are missing. Click Edit > Menus and find the right tools and set them to visible.
You could also try resetting the workspace or pick another one, some workspaces don't (or didn't) have all the tools visible.